# What is Context? How to send Embed object to webhook?

Tags: c#, webhooks, discord.net

I can't figure out how to post Embed message to Discord channel.
I've got my webhook:

```
public DiscordWebhookClient wHook = new DiscordWebhookClient(649622881288537840, "2hQ2XsT7jucOfT4C8-XTsDSys29mPhOF_gFdZ0wBveqzDBR806m0HFl7VR9-ZJxUMRKO");
```

And I have a method to Post my embed message like this, but It says that it has to be IEnumerable instead of Discord.Embed:

```
public async Task SendWebhookAsync(Listing listing)
        {

            EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
            builder.WithTitle(listing.Name);
            builder.WithUrl(listing.Url);
            builder.WithImageUrl(listing.ImageUrl);


            await wHook.SendMessageAsync("", false, builder.Build());
        }
```

I have seen that people use but I don't understand what is context:

```
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, builder.Build());
```

Comment: So just as it says, pass an `IEnumerable`. Webhooks can send multiple embeds at once, so it accepts an `IEnumerable` instead of a single instance of `Embed`. An array containing a single embed should suffice.

Comment: `Context` is used in CommandModules of Discord.Net. Basically it simplifies the access to the current channel. Since you have a `WebhookClient` this won't work for you.

Comment: Just so you know, you shouldn't post webhook urls publicly since people can abuse it to send out `@everyone` or `@here` mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a list out of Your builder.

```
var builders = new List<Embed>() { builder.Build()};
```

Than as third parameter pass builders.

```
await wHook.SendMessageAsync("", false, builders);
```